# How does Rails asset pipeline do preprocessing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, nginx, asset-pipeline, assets

In this [blog](https://launchschool.com/blog/rails-asset-pipeline-best-practices), it says that assets pipeline will compile, compress, and preprocess your assets from your app/assets and then placed the out into `public/assets`. I don't understand the below where it says you can set up a Nginx or Apache server to preprocess your assets for you after the it already has been outputed to the `public/assets`. Is it saying that you can choose to have additional servers such as Apache/Nginx to do the preprocessing for your while the Rails server does the compiling/compressing?

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

> This will create (by default) an assets directory in your public/
>   folder. It will then add all the compressed and compiled files into
>   that directory, in the appropriate formats and with the new digested
>   versions. You can then set up Nginx or Apache to server those files
>   directly so that Rails doesn’t have to deliver them (and run the
>   on-the-fly preprocessing, etc.) itself.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand the below where it says you can set up a Nginx or Apache server to preprocess your assets for you…

It doesn't say that. It does say the following:

> You can then set up Nginx or Apache to server [sic] those files…

There's a difference between *preprocessing* and *serving* files. What this documentation is suggesting is that if you're using a server like nginx, you can configure it to handle requests to assets that exist in your `public/assets` folder. This alleviates your Rails app from handling those requests.

Pre-processing is still handled by Rails in advance of nginx coming into the picture.

Comment: Hi Coreyward, how about the part where the author says, "You can then set up Nginx or Apache to server those files directly so that Rails doesn’t have to deliver them (and run the on-the-fly preprocessing, etc.) itself."

Comment: @stackjlei What about it?

Comment: you said that it doesn't say how Nginx or Apache server can preprocess your assets, but the quote above says it can run the on-the-fly processing - can you explain?

Comment: @stackjlei Please read more carefully. That is not what it says.